# How to find the link for blob present on streaming sites?

Tags: video-streaming

There are various streaming sites and many of them plays a file by collecting segment of the file which are present in m3u8 and then there is an master.m3u8 which contains the quality info of video/audio file.Can someone tell me how to find that where to the link of that master.m3u8 file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: Those are HLS playlists, and they could be anywhere the site owner chooses to put them.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch their url?

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in the Network Traffic tab of your Browser. There is a .m3u8 file. To download this file, you can use Python. Try this:

```
def download_blob_video(stream_url: str, file_name: str):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    caps["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}
    l_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                                options=options,
                                desired_capabilities=caps)

    l_driver.get(stream_url)
    m3u8_url = None
    for request in l_driver.get_log("performance"):
        if ".m3u8" in request["message"]:
            m3u8_url = request["message"].split(" ")[-1].replace('"', "")
            break
    l_driver.quit()
    if m3u8_url is None:
        raise Exception("No m3u8 file found.")

    m3u8_url = m3u8_url.split("url:")[-1].split("}")[0]
    m3u8_obj = m3u8.load(m3u8_url)
    master_playlist = m3u8_obj.playlists[0].absolute_uri
    master_playlist_obj = m3u8.load(master_playlist)

    segments = master_playlist_obj.segments
    base_url = master_playlist_obj.base_uri

    with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        for segment in segments:
            f.write(rq.get(base_url + segment.uri).content)
    return file_name
```

As e.g. you can now feed in a VOE-Stream url. The function finds the .m3u8 file from the traffic and downloads the Video.